# Eclipse - how can I determine the number of methods in a Java application

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to do something weird, I'm trying to determine how many methods has my Java application.

This weird thing has a purpose, it is because I have to improve the logging in the application, and it will require to make a revision of every method and add the logging if it is missing, update the logging if it already has.

I'm in the estimation process, so knowing how many methods has the application will help me to provide a high level estimation with a reasonable basis for this.

Then, here is the question, is there any way to know how many methods has my Java application?

Thanks in advance.

Fer

PS: I'm using Eclipse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a static code analyzer; [Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html), for example, is free SW and has the count you're searching for.

Comment: It is an `exe` file. Anything similar available for `macOs`?

Comment: I don't know if something similar (a Static Code Analyzer) is available specifically on macOs, but you can try to run SourceMonitor with Wine. I hope it will work. Otherwise you can find plenty of good responses to this question below.

Answer (score 33):

Using Eclipse you can do this:

- Press Ctrl-H (Search), then select the "Java Search" tab (if it doesn't appear click on the "Customize..." button at the lower left corner)
- Put * in the search box
- Select "Method" in the "Search For" fieldset
- Select "Declarations" in the "Limit To" fieldset
- Select "Sources" in the "Search In" fieldset
- Select "Workspace" in the "Scope" fieldset
- Click on "Search"

After the search is complete you should see a "XXXX declarations in..." message in the search view and that will be your result.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Great answer too!! thanks. I've compared your method and the results returned by using SourceMonitor, and are very close 5206 method your method and about 5654 methods using sourceMonitor.

Comment: Select "Selected Resource" in the "Scope" fieldset for counting method in the class you are right now.

Comment: This worked for me, especially after I defined a working set, to limit the scope to only two namespaces/projects.  I had to search one term at a time, though, as I couldn't find a way to get any sort of top used methods.

Answer (score 4):

I would prefer using `Reflection`.

- Retrieve all the class from expected packages, where logging is necessary
- Summing up all the method available to all those class

Comment: Thanks for your answer Kowser, I haven't tried, because I was looking for something quicker, however, thanks for sharing your answer

Answer (score 2):

Use sonar - http://www.sonarsource.org/ - it's great tool for analyzing code.

Or look here: [What are the good static code analysis plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/790209/what-are-the-good-static-code-analysis-plugins)

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to add logging to so many methods you might want to consider implementing an AOP solution. It will allow you to write consistent loggers, makes it easier to maintain and doesn't clutter your code with boilerplate stuff. There are countless examples in Google.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I've been looking for and I guess you're talking about Aspected Oriented Programming, is it correct or is it something different?

Answer (score 1):

Metrics is a nice plugin for Eclipse: http://metrics.sourceforge.net/

> Number of Methods (NOM): Total number of methods defined in the selected scope

Answer (score 1):

For a specific class, it's easy just from the class outline panel in eclipse select all methods then right click and copy the fully qualified name to the editor of your choice then it's a simple count lines.

Comment: This is a solution, but it doesn't scale well.

Answer (score 1):

Please press CTRL+O in your respective Java Class in the Eclipse IDE - You will get the number of methods in the respective Java class. 
Now you should be able to see the number of methods available in that class.